# How to convert format of number from English to Italian with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, numbers

I need to convert the English numbering to Italian.

I tried using multiple replacements but I don't think it's the right method.

```vb
price = Replace(price, ".", ",")
```

The problem is that when I have too large numbers I get replaced several times and the wrong numbers come up.

For example:

English version: 3,450.108
After replacement: 3,450,108 (but it's wrong)
Correct format: 3.450,102

Comment: Think you may have a typo in the question which is the correct input `3450.108` or `3450.102`? I've [gone with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427819/692942) `3450.108` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would not recommend [manually replacing values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58397338/692942) in an attempt to get the correct format when VBScript can already do it for you using the [`SetLocale()` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//5xf99h19%28v%3dvs.85%29) in conjunction with the [`FormatNumber()` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ws343esk%28v%3dvs.85%29) which will return the string representation of that number for the specific locale.

> **Note:** Remember that the actual value and how a value is displayed are two separate things *(see the example below)*.

```
Option Explicit
Const decimalplaces = 3
Dim price: price = 3450.108 'This is the raw value from your data source.

Call SetLocale("en-gb")
Call WScript.Echo("English (UK) price: " & FormatNumber(price, decimalplaces))
Call SetLocale("it-it")
Call WScript.Echo("Italian price: " & FormatNumber(price, decimalplaces))
```

Output:

```
English (UK) price: 3,450.108
Italian price: 3.450,108
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to swap 2 delimiter characters you need to use a temp character for the second one, otherwise you won't be able to distinguish between the original second delimiter and the replaced first one.

```vb
price = Replace(price, ".", "_")
price = Replace(price, ",", ".")
price = Replace(price, "_", ",")
```

Comment: What about `SetLocale("it-it")`? *[Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//5xf99h19%28v%3dvs.85%29)*

Comment: @Lankymart Good point. That is indeed a better solution in this scenario.